# Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

**When I run my project everytime it shows the same error Anyone explain How i get rid of this er**ror.

```
`PS C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms> npm run dev

> inventory-management@1.0.0 dev
> concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"

[1] 
[1] > inventory-management@1.0.0 client
[1] > npm start --prefix client
[1]
[0]
[0] > inventory-management@1.0.0 server
[0] > nodemon index.js
[0]
[0] [nodemon] 2.0.20
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[0] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[0] [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
[1] 
[1] > client@0.1.0 start
[1] > react-scripts start
[1]
[0] Server running on PORT 5001
[1] [HPM] Proxy created: /  -> http://localhost:5001
[1] [HPM] Proxy created: /  -> https://dataservices.sypramsoftware.com/api
[1] i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.1.11/
[1] i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
[1] i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\public
[1] i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
[1] Starting the development server...
[1]
[1] Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
[1]     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
[1]     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
[1]     at module.exports (C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
[1]     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
[1]     at handleParseError (C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
[1]     at C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
[1]     at C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
[1]     at C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
[1]     at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
[1]     at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
[1] C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
[1]   throw err;
[1]   ^
[1]
[1] Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
[1]     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
[1]     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
[1]     at module.exports (C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
[1]     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
[1]     at C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
[1]     at C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
[1]     at C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
[1]     at C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
[1]     at context.callback (C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
[1]     at C:\vervebot\trinethra_icms\client\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
[1]   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
[1]   library: 'digital envelope routines',
[1]   reason: 'unsupported',
[1]   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
[1] }
[1]
[1] Node.js v18.12.1
[1] npm run client exited with code 1`
```

[image]

**This is the Screenshot, It will help to get an clear idea.**

**I also use npm audit fix --force but i have to delete npm module and reinstall again. After doing all this i recive the same error again.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have node.js 17 or above installed on your machine. This error occurs because node.js 17 onwards uses OpenSSL3, which has changed the code for the initialization context of md family (including md4), and this is a breaking change.
you can solve this issue in several ways,

change your 'start' script in package.json in to
`"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"`

or you can downgrade your node version, you can use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md) to quickly install and use different versions of node via the command line.